# Circular Gradient and WPF

Tags: wpf, gradient, psd

I need to replicate a circular (or angle) gradient from a Photoshop comp in WPF; so far I can only find linear and radial. Does anyone know if such a thing exists, or and easy way to get get a circular gradient in WPF?

Note: I'm not asking about a radial gradient. A circular gradient is like taking a rectangle, applying a gradient and then transforming the rectangle into a circle.

Comment: I'm voting to close this, as it's an exact duplicate of a newer question (that now has an answer!)

Comment: (I do like your description/explanation of the radial gradient, though...ideally, it should be brought over into the other question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184127/how-to-implement-a-conical-cone-circular-gradient-in-wpf) for a new and a bit more complete answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

While I've never done this before (so I don't know what's involved) you could implement a type that inherits from [`GradientBrush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.gradientbrush.aspx). I don't think this is trivial though.

I've also not worked with Photoshop circular gradients, but from your description I can't help but think that you could at least approximate it using a [`LinearGradientBrush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.lineargradientbrush.aspx) and then transforming the result - perhaps using a [`MatrixTransform`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.matrixtransform.aspx).

Sorry that I can't give you concrete answers, but maybe these suggestions can point you in the right direction.

Comment: Yes, well, I was hoping to not have to write all of that. Kind of a bummer that doesn't appear to be there.